Oracle PL/SQL - Changing Number formats using Numeric masks
I am having requirement where customer can enter a number in any format and I need to convert it into valid number format using plsql code  dynamically. could you please guide me.

Test case1# (200.000,00) Formatted number: -200000.00
Test case2# (200,000.00) Formatted number: -200000.00
Test Case3# (20000) Formatted number: -20000.00
Test Case4# 1000000 Formatted number: 1000000.00
Test Case5# (20,000.00) Formatted number: -20000.00
Test Case6# 10,000,000 Formatted number: 10000000.00
Test Case7# 12.5 Formatted number: 12.50
Test Case8# 12,5 Formatted number: 12.50

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.
I tried below code However its not working for all scenarios.
SELECT 
    attribute2,
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(Number, '^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?$') THEN 
            TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(Number, '.', ''), '999999.99')
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(Number, '^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$') THEN 
            TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(Number, ',', ''), '999999.99')
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS formatted_amount
FROM TEST ;


So, you want to accept the comma as decimal separator and dot as thousand separator, but also dot as decimal separator and comma as thousand separator. Which leads us to: Does 1.000 equal 1 or 1000? Does 1,000 equal 1 or 1000?

You tagged your request with plsql. But your approach uses SQL, not PL/SQL. Are you looking for a PL/SQL solution (i.e. a function in Oracle's programming language PL/SQL) or for a SQL solution for an Oracle database?

Hi Thorsten
We have multiple customers and each customer will give input values different. we need to handle it dynamically. PFB the details for that-
Test case1#
User Input Value:   (200.000,00)
Converted Input Value:  -200000
Formatted number:   -200000.00
Test case2#
User Input Value:  (200,000.00)
Converted Input Value: :-200000
Formatted number: -200000.00
Test Case3#
User Input Value:  (20000)
Converted Input Value: -20000
Formatted number: -20000.00
Test Case4#
User Input Value: 1000000
Converted Input Value: 1000000
Formatted number: 1000000.00

Test Case5#
User Input Value: (20,000.00)
Converted Input Value: -20000
Formatted number: -20000.00
Test Case6#
User Input Value: 10,000,000
Converted Input Value: 10000000
Formatted number: 10000000.00
Test Case7#
User Input Value: 12.5
Converted Input Value: 12.5
Formatted number: 12.50
Test Case8#
User Input Value: 12,5
Converted Input Value: 12.5
Formatted number: 12.50

You don't have to repeat what you have already written in your request. Just answer the two questions. Does 1.000 equal 1 or 1000? Does 1,000 equal 1 or 1000?

And you haven't reacted to my other comment either. You tagged this plsql. Do you work with Oracle? Than tag oracle. Does it matter whether you get an SQL or a PL/SQL solution? You probably want to tag at least sql.

Well, whatever way you look at it, you are fighting a system design flaw here. These "numbers" should never make it into a database. If the data gets entered via an app, the app should know the real number and save it in a numeric database column. If the data gets entered via text files, then the numeric format used in the files should be explicitly defined, so there is no guessing what the dot or comma might mean...

... As is, it is possible for the strings to contain any garbage or ambiguous values. This should not be tackled with SQL, but with a proper programming language (PL/SQL). Check for invalid characters, check whether there are parantheses and whether they are in the right place. Use rules to determine decimal separator and thousand separator and ensure the decimal separator doesn't occur more than once and that the thousand separator is only located in valid positions. Then decide: do you want the function to return NULL on invalid data or rather raise an exception?

@ThorstenKettner
Does 1.000 equal 1 or 1000?   => 1000
Does 1,000 equal 1 or 1000?  => 1000

And this is because...? What is the rule you apply here to decide that no matter whether the comma or the dot is a thousand separator and not a decimal separator? You'll have to define a precise set of rules in order to tell the two separators from each other in every possible constellation.

I wonder ... Above I have already given you the answer how to solve this. Use the programming language PL/SQL and parse the string applying all necessary rules to end up with the correct number. Is there anything else you must know? Any help you need from us? Otherwise, just write that function and close this request.
